# OnReceive Not Working In Android GCM

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying GCM in my project, but I am not getting through. 
to debug I placed the Toast in the OnReceive, But again that's not working.

I am using genymotion, but when I install the APK in mobile it works fine.

My Code Is

```
 Intent RegInt = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
        RegInt.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Home.this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        RegInt.putExtra("sender", "123456");
        startService(RegInt);
```

My OnReceive Is

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        String action = "";
        action = arg1.getAction();
        String regId = "";
        if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            regId = arg1.getStringExtra("registration_id");
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(arg0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("reg", regId);
            editor.putString("valid", "1");
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Action: " + arg1.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

My Manifest Looks Like

```
 <receiver
    android:name="my.package.riyaz.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"

        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="my.package.riyaz" android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I think you are going wrong with your integration. Refer this https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: i figured out one thing, it works fine on mobile but does not work on genymotion

Comment: GCM does not work on emulator, you need a real device to register to GCM then receive registrationId.

Comment: Thanks i tested on real device and it worked

Answer (score 0):

After Lot of research i figured it out that GCM is not working emulator